# Is there a way to send keys to a selenium window without finding a element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to send keys to the whole driver window in the background. So I can have a game window open and the driver will have keys sent to it.

I need to send the keys to just that window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send keys to the `body` element of the web page. It will actually be equally to sending the text to a whole driver window.
This can be done as following:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body').send_keys("The text you want to send")
```